# Issue with Protocols with Associated Types in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, protocols, swift-protocols

I have one framework ProviderFramework with the following contents:

```
public class Provider {

    public func fun(some: Model) {

    }

}

public class Model {

    public let id: Int

    init(id: Int) {
        self.id = id
    }

}
```

and another UserFramework with the following contents:

```
public protocol ProviderProtocol {

    func fun(some: ModelProtocol)

}

public protocol ModelProtocol {

    var id: Int {get}

}
```

What I want is to make the Provider class conform to the ProviderProtocol class. So in a framework that imports both of the previously mentioned frameworks I have this:

```
extension ProviderFramework.Model: UserFramework.ModelProtocol {}
extension ProviderFramework.Provider: UserFramework.ProviderProtocol {}
```

Unfortunately, this results in an error for the second conformance.
So, I tried using an associated types and my ProviderProtocol turned into this:

```
public protocol ProviderProtocol {

    associatedtype T: ModelProtocol

    func fun(some: T)

}
```

and the problematic conformance to this:

```
extension ProviderFramework.Provider: UserFramework.ProviderProtocol {
    public typealias T = ProviderFramework.Model
}
```

Now there aren't any compile errors, but if I want to use the Protocol as a type like this:

```
class Consumer {

    var provider: ProviderProtocol?

}
```

I again get an error: 'Protocol 'ProviderProtocol' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements'

I would want to be able to do the last thing. Do I have some bug in my code or if not is there some alternative solution for this problem?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to the second approach, why not use Provider instead of ProviderProtocol? Since you confirmed `typealias T` as `ProviderFramework.Model` in the extension of class `Provider`.

```
class Consumer {
    var provider: Provider?
}
```

Comment: This:

extension Provider: ProviderProtocol {
    public func fun(some: ModelProtocol) {
    }
}

adds another function to the Provider class which is not my point. I want to get the
public func fun(some: Model)
function to somehow make the Provider class conform to the ProviderProtocol so that the original method will be called when calling for the fun function.

Comment: Why not change class Provider directly? Sounds like the Provider class is locked, cannot change it? So you want use extension to override the original behavior?

Comment: If I change the Provider class to conform to the ProviderProtocol I will have to import the UserFramework in the ProviderFramework which creates a dependency between them that I don't want. I want to resolve the dependency in a third class outside of the frameworks that imports both of them.

Comment: The Consumer class is part of the UserFramework so using the Provider class directly there would require an import of the ProviderFramework in the UserFramework which I don't want. I want the UserFramework and the ProviderFramework to be independent of each other and have another class that imports both of them connect them.